# Django manage.py only returning list of subcommands and options

Tags: python, django, manage.py

I'm sure I'm overlooking something very simple, but I've tried multiple times and still run into the same problem.

I have installed **Python 2.7.1** and **Django 1.2.4** on **Windows Vista**.

I create a project using *django-admin startproject projectname*. It successfully creates the folders and files needed.

I then try running *manage.py runserver* and all I receive in return is the available commands and options for manage.py.

What am I missing here? I see no output other than this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you run *manage.py runserver* and if you have, then try *python manage.py runserver*?

Comment: cool! It's strange on one machine I have manage.py runserver and on another machine i have to also go python manage.py runserver. ^_^

Comment: Quite possible; check the file associations, presumable one machine has .py configured to automatically run with Python and the other doesn't.